By using the correspondence theorem, show that the Jacobson radical of R/J(R) = (0)
By using the correspondence theorem (of ideals and quotients) (not by using units), show that the Jacobson radical of R/J(R) = (0)
Where R is a commutative ring, and J(R) is the Jacobson's radical; the intersection of all maximal ideals of R.
Thank you!

Please show your attempt.

In the linked dupe there is a link to the proof. https://planetmath.org/aringmoduloitsjacobsonradicalissemiprimitive

The second linked dupe has the proof in the answers.
